# How to Call Modal Bootstrap in Controller Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to add message to my form when success or failed send the message. To showing message i use pop up bootstrap. I want to call the code in `echo`

I'm very confuse to call the modal bootstrap in my controller?

I'm using a framework Codeigniter with `Bootstrap`

This is My **Controller**

```
public function submitsemail(){
if( $input_name !='' && $input_email !='' && $input_codetrans !='' && $input_pict !=''){


    $this->load->library('email');

    $mail_message = "
       Information Transaction : <br/>    
       Name: $input_name <br/>
       Email: $input_email <br/>
       Code: $input_codetrans <br/>
    ";
    $this->email->from('xxxxx@xxxxx.id', 'Support CS Ultra');
    $this->email->to('xxxx@xxxx.com');
    $attched_file= "gambar/".$data['file_name'];
    $this->email->attach($attched_file);
    $this->email->subject('Confirm Transaction');
    $this->email->message($mail_message);
    $this->email->send();

    echo '(Call Pop Up Modal Bootstrap Success)';
  } else {
    echo '(Call Pop Up Modal Bootstrap Failed)';
  }
}
```

**Success**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Success</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Success Confirm The Payment.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
      </div>
```

**Failed**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Failed</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Please check your form before Submit.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: you can't afaik. you can echo an alert, but that isn't very pretty nor is it good practice. best bet is to either use flash messages (since you are refreshing/redirecting anyways) or use ajax and open a model in the success function.

Comment: oh okay, but im a newbie in ajax. Can you give me a example code to showing pop up message? :D

Comment: You can use Sweet Alert - https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/

Comment: If i'm use sweetalert, to call this in my view page? So to better ways i'm use pop up in my view page, not in my controller?

Comment: I didn't get you @GloriaMahena?

Comment: sweetalert is plugin in bootstrap? and before to use it, install in my bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you call this action by ajax? Very simple, just make 2 hidden buttons target to your modals (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp). When ajax calling complete, read the response to decide choose which button will be clicked (use .click() by jquery)

Comment: can you give more details information about 2 hidden button target?

Comment: Like this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8BJYEFLSC2C
After receive ajax response, you can call ```$('#success-btn').click()``` or ```$('#failure-btn').click()```